# Query - find empty interval in series of timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

I have a table that stores historical data. I get a row inserted in this query every 30 seconds from different type of sources and obviously there is a time stamp associated.

Let's make my parameter as disservice to 1 hour.

Since I charge my services based on time, I need to know, for example, in a specific month, if there is a period within this month in which the there is an interval which is equal or exceeds my 1 hour interval.

A simplified structure of the table would be like:

```
tid serial primary key,
tunitd id int,
tts timestamp default now(),
tdescr text
```

I don't want to write a function that loops through all the records comparing them one by one as I suppose it is time and memory consuming.

Is there any way to do this directly from SQL maybe using the interval type in PostgreSQL?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, it is possible with SQL. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

this small SQL query will display all gaps with the duration more than one hour:

```
select tts, next_tts, next_tts-tts as diff from
(select a.tts, min(b.tts) as next_tts
from test1 a
inner join test1 b ON a.tts < b.tts
GROUP BY a.tts) as c
where next_tts - tts > INTERVAL '1 hour'
order by tts;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/51cc1/1)